# Compile c code as c#

Tags: c#, c++, compilation

Hi this may be a strange question but I have some c++ code that I would like to compile as c# code using Visual Studio 2012.

The code its self is completely compatible and will compile with both compilers.

What I would like to do is have the c# compiler treat the .c files as .cs files and compile them as c#, the reason for this is I still need this particular c++ file for an old library but dont want to have two copies of the code when I update something.

Currently I have a batch file that copies the .c code from the c++ project within a solution to the c# project within the same solution and it then uses a pre processor and compiles it however I obviously loose breakpoints, etc and it is a bit of a problem.

Comment: Waht is the Error or Issue ./

Comment: Why not converting your C code to a .dll and importing it in your C# code?

Comment: It might compile with both compilers, but unless it is "somewhat trivial" (or being all `#define FOO`-like statements), I doubt it has the same expected behavior or characteristics. You might want to provide more information on the actual code.

Comment: You really should post some code - it sounds too strange to use code for C# *and* an "old library".

Answer (score 0):

The file Extension is not relevant just set the Build Action to Compile in the Properties of the file. Syntax Highlighting might have some problems with that but not the compiler.